# Do I need to call for .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, for-loop, call

I have no experience with .htaccess, but I got a tip that it's very useful so I wanted to try this.

I now have a file called .htaccess, in my root folder.
The files contains this;

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kellyvuijst\.nl [nc]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.kellyvuijst.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

What I'm trying to do here is create a 'www.mysite.com/portfolio/' instead of 'mysite.com/portfolio.html' I used some tutorials on this and I think it's correct, but I'm not sure.

So now I have this file, and what now? The tutorials all show what to put in the file but not what to do with it? Do I need to call for it in every .html page I have? And how do I call for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, you're using a lot of rules here to achieve just that.

Anyway, no you don't have to include that file. If you're hosting your site on a server with Apache it'll be included automatically. Can you also run PHP files or is your site just HTML? That's always an easy sign if you're also using Apache (not 100%, but often the go together).

If so, you could try just using these rules first:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.+)\.(.+)$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1.%2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If that always adds www to your address, even if you type in the URL without www at least you can be certain that it works.

Then, to make the .html disappear you can add this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule $(.*)/$ /$1.html [L]
```

This should make every url that ends with a slash (like portfolio/) use a .html file instead (portfolio.html), but only if /portfolio/ isn't an actual directory on your website.

(I removed your url from the rules because this way it should also work if you use it on another website, or if you change your url. It should still do what you want)

Answer (score 2):

A .htaccess file is automatically invoked by the server.

You have just to put this into your file :

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule www.mysite.com/portfolio/ /mysite.com/portfolio.html [L]
```

Comment: `www.mysite.com/portfolio/` isn't the URI

Answer (score 0):

Made sure the server is configured to allow htaccess files to override host options. So in your vhost/server config, you need:

```
AllowOverride All
```